Почему при установке jupyter notebook выходит такая ошибка сервера?
При установке ЮПИТЕР нооутбука выходит такая ошибка:

[E 2024-08-27 10:48:43.746 ServerApp] Failed to write server-info to C:\Users\ICH\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\jpserver-9860.json: PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied')

Что делать ?

При установке или при запуске?
